# HTML <br /> inside a Select Box

Tags: html, css, html-select

I would like to know if there is anyway I can divide an item on two line inside a select box.

One of the values of my select box is two long to fit in my div.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is impossible.

You can consider using a javascript widget, like [this](http://sharebrain.info/brainpicks/scripting/jquerycombobox-dropdown-list/3873/) jQuery plug-in.

May I also say that what you are trying to do is uncommon - even in desktop applications users don't expect to find wrapped text in a drop-down box and may get confused if they do see one. It would be better to try a different control or try to limit the text.

Comment: The link is outdated.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible, but if it's simply a matter of avoiding that the element gets too wide you could just define a width (eg. `<select style="width:100px;">`). This will cause text to be cut off when the box is "closed", but as soon as you "open" it the entire text will be shown.

Comment: Setting a fixed width on select will make it hard to read options longer then that width in IE.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's impossible. However, I'd look at **jQuer**y for options. Specifically, there are **jQuery** plugins that allow for select box customization.

**[Select Box Factory 2.0](http://theuiguy.blogspot.com/2008/09/select-box-factory-20-for-jquery.html)** is one option. I believe it extends the functionality of the select box to allow text wrapping among other features.

Answer (score 1):

You could simple add an option disabled in blank

`<option disabled selected value>  </option>`

Comment: Can you provide an example? Just to make this a high quality answer

Answer (score 0):

> Divide an item that's on two lines in a select box.

Why would you want to do that? If you're using a JQuery plugin to make HTML display inside an option tag, then there would be no reason to ask this question, I don't think, as you would be already able to add a 
 tag.

What you can do to make spacing in select elements, is to create a blank option tag, that has an empty value and name. You would then have to validate the submission to detect if a blank value was submitted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really in need, a hacky solution would be to take a screenshot of the text on two lines, and use images in your select box.

http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/05/how-to-add-images-in-dropdown-list.html

Just be sure to set the `alt` tag on the images for accessibility.